# THREE.js OBJ Loader Objects

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, three.js

I have a problem regarding accessing the object outside the event boundries. If I put the object in an array and checkout that array the array is also empty but in the event scope it is full. I need to know that how could I access the object outside the event scope.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++){
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
        var tree = event.content;
        myWorld.setWorldTreePosition(multiplier);

        tree.position.y = 0;
        tree.position.x = myWorld.myTreePosition.position.x;
        tree.position.z =  myWorld.myTreePosition.position.z;
        tree.rotation.x = -(Math.PI / 2);
        tree.scale.set(10,5,5);
        scene.add( tree );
        collidableMeshList2.push(tree);

        tree.castShadow = true;
        //collidableMeshList.push(tree);
        multiplier += 500;

        console.log(collidableMeshList2); // here it is full of trees.
    }
);

loader.load( 'obj/Palm_Tree.obj', 'obj/Palm_Tree.mtl' );
//outside this all becomes empty.

console.log(collidableMeshList2); // here is list is empty but I don't know why.
```

Comment: You should at least move the file line of the loop outside it. You can add many listeners to one loader I think but if you re-define the object in the loop, it will get replaced each time. Update the question with this so that you get better responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about the scope; It's empty because you need to wait for the loader to load the object before you'll see the trees in there - which is what the addEventListener("load") does. The last line of your code snippet executes before your load function.

Your code snippet is confusing, it's not immediately apparent what you are trying to do with the for loop. You are creating many loaders and attaching load event listener to them. But your loader.load() call is after the loop, so it will apply to the last loader. You'll probably want to move your loader object creation up outside the for loop, or the loader.load call inside the loop.

Comment: **loader.load()** is with in the loop so this apply to every loader. Secondly i tried this without the loop but that did not work too. I made the loop as I want to load object again and again as I required to place the tree object in my game at different places.